# Degree of the projection map on (real) projective space

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am studying Outerelo/Ruiz [Mapping Degree Theory](https://books.google.es/books?id=K94tfITNWucC&lpg=PP1&dq=0821849158&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false), and I do not know how to solve the following problem:

> Let $\pi: \mathbb{S}^n \to \mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$ be the canonical surjection. Compute the degree of $\pi$.

Here, the degree of $f$ is $$\operatorname{deg}f = \sum_{x \in f^{-1}(y)}\operatorname{sgnt}_x(f)$$ with $\operatorname{sgnt}_x(f) = 1$ if $f$ is orientation preserving in $x$ and $\operatorname{sgnt}_x(f) = -1$ is $f$ is orientation reversing in $x$. Also, $y$ is a regular value of $f$.

Now, with the theory that the book develops, I know that the degree does not deppend on the choice of $y$. So, in order to compute $\operatorname{deg}(\pi)$, I need to find a regular value $y$ of $\pi$ and study the orientations on $\pi^{-1}(y)$.

My questions are:

- Is my reasoning correct?
- How do I find the regular values of $\pi$?

Comment: Do you know that $\pi$ is a local diffeomorphism? That should make clear what the regular values of $\pi$ are. Also, you will have to consider the parity of $n$ as $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$ only is orientable for odd $n$.

Comment: Ah, of course - every $y \in \mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$ is a regular value. Thank you.